# Confused about setting the value of @transactional

Tags: java, spring, transactional

Can anybody explain me that when I should put `readOnly` value as `true` and when I should set it as `false` when using it with `@Transactional` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are only reading/selecting from the database and not changing any data - by performing an update/insert/delete.

If you can specify readOnly you should as its much less resource intensive.

Answer (score 2):

the definition is pretty straight-forward: You may use `readonly=true` if and only if you assure no update, insert or delete operation takes place inside the transaction.
This optimizes the locking behaviour of your dbms, if supported.

`readonly` is false by default.

best regards,

sam

**Edit**

```
/**
 * {@code true} if the transaction is read-only.
 * Defaults to {@code false}.
 * <p>This just serves as a hint for the actual transaction subsystem;
 * it will <i>not necessarily</i> cause failure of write access attempts.
 * A transaction manager which cannot interpret the read-only hint will
 * <i>not</i> throw an exception when asked for a read-only transaction.
 * @see org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttribute#isReadOnly()
 */
boolean readOnly() default false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Customizing the isolation level you add more control to your transactions.

If you know that a method will be read-only you should specify it.

With readonly=true you are saying to the transaction manager that one particular method will only read from the DB. This has two advantages:

First, it can be faster than the others, because it allows the DBMS to optimize the transaction (if supported). 
Secondly it could save you from deadlock problems (when for example a specific table is write-locked), because you are assuring that the method won't execute INSERT or UPDATE.

However, here you can find all the details about it:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html